# Generate table Using index array

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using Office 2021, I tried a lot of ways but with only disappointment, no luck yet.

I have a table with items and prices for each shop.

main table

[image]

I want to auto-generate two tables, one for each shop, containing the items that sell cheaper on that shop and its price.

shop 1 table

[image]

shop 2 table

[image]

I tried several index arrays but couldn't manage to succeed. please help.

edit:
confused about a bot message stating that the question is not clear, so ill explain more:

I need to split the main table into 2 tables, one for each shop.
each shop table contains items that are cheaper in that said shop.

For example, if sugar is cheaper in shop 1 on the main table, then it should be included in shop 1 table and not in shop 2.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you must have tables then use Power Query to return your columns but you'll need to refresh. If you don't need tables then use `FILTER()` to return the rows you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a third column in the main table "cheapest" with the formula:

```
=IF(B2<C2,1,2)
```

Now filter for either 1 or 2.

If you need to generate two seperate tables, use the FILTER formula in office 365.